# Meteor refresh subscription in iron-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze

I have a 1000+ document in user collection. I should display 10 user per page. subscribe next 10 users in `onclick` event. Everything is works fine. But when I go to another route the subscription count remains same.

**Router.js:**

```
    Router.map(function() {
      this.route('user.india', {path: '/user/india', layoutTemplate: 'userLayout'});
      this.route('user.us', {path: '/user/us', layoutTemplate: 'userLayout'});
    });
```

**Templates**

```
<template name="userLayout">
  {{> yield}}
  {{> _tabs}}
</template>
<template name="userIndia">
    {{#each user}}
           {{name}}
    {{/each}}
      <div id="loadMore">Load More</div>
    {{> _tabs}}
</template>
<template name="userUs">
    {{#each user}}
           {{name}}
    {{/each}}
      <div id="loadMore">Load More</div>
  {{> _tabs}}
</template>
```

**Client**

```
//Indian User
ITEMS_INCREMENT = 10;
Template.userIndia.created = function () {
  Session.setDefault('itemsLimit', ITEMS_INCREMENT);
  this.autorun(function () {
    this.subscription = Meteor.subscribe('user','IN', Session.get('itemsLimit'));
  }.bind(this));
};
Template.userIndia.helpers({
  Bids : function(){
    return User.find();
  }
});

//US users
ITEMS_INCREMENT = 10;
Template.userUs.created = function () {
  Session.setDefault('itemsLimit', ITEMS_INCREMENT);
  this.autorun(function () {
    this.subscription = Meteor.subscribe('user','IN', Session.get('itemsLimit'));
  }.bind(this));
};
Template.userUs.helpers({
  Bids : function(){
    return User.find();
  }
});
```

**Server**

```
  Meteor.publish('user', function(country, limit) {
    return Users.find({'country':country}, { limit: limit });
  });
```

Comment: `But when I go to another route` this means from `/user/india` to `/user/us` route?

Comment: `ITEMS_INCREMENT` how are you setting this value?

Comment: @Sasikanth : checkout my edited question.

Comment: One more question `subscription count remains same`  means when you're in /users/india route if the limit count is 50(assume you click loadmore 4 times) and when you goto `/users/us` route count is still 50. Is that your issue?

Comment: @Sasikanth: Yes exactly.

Comment: @Sasikanth If I move to other routes the subscription collection is automatically destroyed. but `userIndia` and `userUs` is in same Layout. I think that's why the problem occurs.

Comment: please try my answer and let me know the result

Comment: Be sure to use the syntax `Template.x.onCreated(function () { ... });` as `Template.x.created = function () { ... };` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @CaptSaltyJack. Ill use `onCreated`

Answer (score 1):

Continue from the comments, the limit count preservs between routes because you're usig `Session` variables to store the limit count.

Session data is preserved between the routes that means eventhough you change the routes session value will be same
check docs here http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session

there are two solutions here either you need to use `reactivevars` or `reactivedict`

or

Use two different session variables for two different subscriptions like

```
ITEMS_INCREMENT = 10;
Template.userIndia.created = function () {
  Session.setDefault('itemsLimitIndia', ITEMS_INCREMENT);
  this.autorun(function () {
    this.subscription = Meteor.subscribe('user','IN', Session.get('itemsLimitIndia'));
  }.bind(this));
};
Template.userIndia.helpers({
  Bids : function(){
    return User.find();
  }
});

//US users
ITEMS_INCREMENT = 10;
Template.userUs.created = function () {
  Session.setDefault('itemsLimitUS', ITEMS_INCREMENT);
  this.autorun(function () {
    this.subscription = Meteor.subscribe('user','IN', Session.get('itemsLimitUS'));
  }.bind(this));
};
```

note I changed session variables names

Comment: session variable is resetting on  `created` function of `/user/india` and `user/us`. I think the problem is `publish`. 1st time when I hit `/user/india` server publish 10 users in India. 2nd time I hit `/user/us` so server publish 10 US users to local collection. Now I have 20 users in local collection. This is the problem.  I tried different publisher name for inida and US. Now it works fine.

Comment: Okay,if you use two different publications server is publishing data everytime you change the data, with the same publication and your previous code you can cache the results without sending data everytime you changes route.by just editing the helpers in `us` and `india` templates to `return Users.find({'country':'Us or In`}, { limit: Session.get('itemsLimit') });`